# Docker on Raspberry Pi. 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspberry-pi, docker

I tried to install Docker on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10). Most websites show that it can be done in just one or two command lines.

`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`
or
`curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh && sh get-docker.sh`

However, none of them work and they both give me the same error.

> E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate

What is wrong? How can I install it? The Raspbian is just newly installed.

Comment: What says `dpkg -l '*docker*'`on your RPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug specific to this script and Docker installation on Raspbian Buster](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39417)  which hasn't been fully resolved yet. You can find a workaround [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/how-to-fix-docker-for-raspbian-buster/).

Comment: It works. In the website you gave me, it states that the docker team do not release the package to rpi buster yet. But if you look those link for download deb package. `**/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/arm/**`. It does seem like they have the package for buster, right?